# Scrolling a GridView by ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION and swapping items in the Gridview's ArrayAdapter on ACTION_DROP

Tags: java, android, gridview, drag-and-drop, android-arrayadapter

I want a user to be able to swap items (an `ImageView` in a `RelativeLayout`) in a `GridView`, but I also want them to be able to scroll the `GridView` up or down if they drag the image to the top or the bottom of the `GridView`, respectivley.

If I implement the drag listener in the backing `ArrayAdapter`, I can't do the scrolling.
If I implement it in the `GridView` as shown below, I can't get the position of the array item that I drop at.

Is there any way to do this? Note the comment where I'm having the problem. Thanks!

I have a `GridView` that implements `OnDragListener`, but I can't figure out how to get the position I want to swap.

Here's the long click listener:

```
gv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> grv, View v,
                int position, long row) {
            mVibrator.vibrate(VIBRATE_DURATION);
            ClipData cd = ClipData.newPlainText("position", String.valueOf(position));
            v.startDrag(cd, new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), v, 0);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Here's my drag Listener:

```
 gv.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {

        Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
        Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

        private static final int THRESHHOLD = 200;

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

            int height = v.getMeasuredHeight();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                v.setBackground(enterShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setBackground(enterShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.setBackground(normalShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:

                float y = event.getY();
                if (height - y < THRESHHOLD) {
                    gv.smoothScrollBy(200, 300);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Scrolling DOWN");
                } else if (height - y > height - THRESHHOLD) {
                    gv.smoothScrollBy(-200, 300);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Scrolling UP");
                }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                //Gridview position to swap with.
                // HOW DO I GET THIS?
                int i = position;
                int j = Integer.parseInt(event.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getText().toString());
                Collections.swap(mUriList, i, j);
                Log.i(TAG, "Swapped " + i+ " with " + j);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                v.setBackground(null);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to make the GridView final and use `gv.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());` to get the position.

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
    //Gridview position to swap with.
    int i =gv.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
    int j = Integer.parseInt(event.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getText().toString());
    Collections.swap(mUriList, i, j);
    Log.i(TAG, "Swapped " + i+ " with " + j);
    break;
```